# Store a selected Core Data row in SwiftUI AppStorage

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have a SwiftUI picker that displays a single option for each row in a Core Data table; I use a name attribute (a String) to show to the user, and use an id attribute (a UUID) to store which option the user has chosen. This chosen value is saved to an AppStorage variable (as a string), so each time I run the app, it remembers which UUID I chose.

However, every time I run the app, the UUID for each option changes, so I can't use this method. Should Core Data/Swift run like this, if so, how should I do what I'm trying to do above? Many thanks.

I expected when applying a UUID to the id attribute (a UUID) in Core Data, it would store a unique value that would remain the same whenever I ran my code, however it doesn't seem to do this.

---

In Core Data, there are only 2 attributes in my vehicle entity; id (UUID) and name (String)

This is how I create an item (hard coded for this example):

```
let newVehicle = Vehicle(context: viewContext)
newVehicle.id = UUID()
newVehicle.name = "My Vehicle"
```

This is how it's displayed (I don't normally display the UUID, I'm just doing this to check it changes every time I run the app):

```
Picker("Vehicle", selection: $selectedVehicleId) {
    ForEach(myVehicles) { vehicle in
        Text("\(vehicle.name) - \(vehicle.id.uuidString)").tag(vehicle.id.uuidString)
    }
}
```

This is how it's stored:

```
@AppStorage("selected vehicle id") var selectedVehicleId: String = "not selected"
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some of your code? That'll help people who want to try and provide an answer. Thanks

Comment: Use an id that doesn't change

Comment: Your id (UUID) shouldn’t change for an object if you persist it in Core Data so there must be something else going on here.